# PHP script is executing multiple times when only invoked once on the command line. Only output of first run is sent to stdout

Tags: php, windows-7, cygwin, command-line-interface

Everytime I invoke a PHP script via the command line in windows (either in cygwin or cmd) the script seems to be running multiple (6) times, however only the output of the first run is sent to the screen's output. It's a very weird problem, a little tricky to describe.

test.php:

```
<?php
$t = microtime();
error_log($t . "\n", 3, 'test.out');
echo $t;
?>
```

I run the script **once**, and this is the result

```
$ php test.php;
0.97800300 1292476780
$ cat test.out
0.97800300 1292476780
0.04000200 1292476781
0.09500200 1292476781
0.14700200 1292476781
0.19900200 1292476781
0.25600300 1292476781
```

Across different test files, and different versions of PHP, it seems to consistently run 6 times. 
It Doesn't matter if I run the script through cygwin or the windows shell. 
I've Tried using php5.2.6 and php5.2.7 and php5.2.11 - all installed via WAMP.
I tried using strace, but its output was blank - I've never used it on windows before, perhaps my cygwin installation isn't correct. I'm using windows 7, and the problem started when I started using windows 7. I have a colleague running windows 7 and he has the exact same problem, however everyone (including my former self) running windows xp has no problem at all with the php CLI.

I hope I'm not missing anything obvious here! Let me know anything else I can provide, and if anyone has any ideas or advice I would be most grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it now looks like an error in the versions/builds of PHP I'm using, as testing with different versions of PHP will not produce the same error. I clearly made an error in my above post (and testing yesterday) and didn't correctly test with the different versions.

Updated test.php

```
<?php
$t = microtime();
error_log($t."\n", 3, $argv[1]);
echo $t;
?>
```

And running with 5.2.6, 5.2.7 and 5.2.11

```
Paul@Paul-Macbook-W7 ~
$ /cygdrive/c/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.6/php test.php test-526.out
0.20960200 1292539753
Paul@Paul-Macbook-W7 ~
$ cat test-526.out
0.20960200 1292539753
0.27060200 1292539753
0.32160200 1292539753
0.37460200 1292539753
0.42460200 1292539753
0.47660200 1292539753

Paul@Paul-Macbook-W7 ~
$ /cygdrive/c/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.7/php test.php test-527.out
0.32660200 1292539767
Paul@Paul-Macbook-W7 ~
$ cat test-527.out
0.32660200 1292539767

Paul@Paul-Macbook-W7 ~
$ /cygdrive/c/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.11/php test.php test-5211.out
0.70760500 1292539776
Paul@Paul-Macbook-W7 ~
$ cat test-5211.out
0.70760500 1292539776
```

So I guess at this stage I can only conclude it's a bug in the php build I've got for 5.2.6: `PHP 5.2.6 (cli) (built: May  2 2008 18:02:07)`

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed really weird...
Try this

```
<?php
$t = microtime();
file_put_contents('test.out', $t);
echo $t;
?>
```

Comment: It essentially does the same, but only the last run's time ends up in test.out because by default file_put_contents() overwrites a file not appends it. The script I provided was really only trying to illustrate the problem. The actual thing that is causing this issue is I'm running selenium tests via php cli, and the tests are all running 6 times each.

Comment: So it is probably related to Selenium

Comment: I don't think that's the case. That's why I provided the above example.

Comment: So it appears that I have made an error in my previous testing, and therefore in the above post. I must have only tried using php v5.2.6, only installing the other versions.